# Getting the student position in the whole class

Tags: mysql, ranking

Below is my code. 
What i want to do is to get each student`s position base on the overall raw score of the class.
I use 'sum(assessment)' to sum the overall sores.

my error is'[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function'

```
SELECT 
    SUM(assessment) AS raw_score,
    student.id,
    student.fname,
    student.oname,
    student.lname,
    class.class,
    FIND_IN_SET(
    SUM(assessment),
        (
            SELECT
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                    DISTINCT sum(assessment) 
                    ORDER BY
                sum(assessment)  DESC
                )
            FROM
                all_exam_records
        )
    ) AS position
FROM
    all_exam_records
INNER JOIN student ON student.id = all_exam_records.student_name
INNER JOIN class ON class.id = student.class
WHERE class.id = '440'
GROUP BY class.id
```

Comment: `WHERE class.id = '440'
GROUP BY class.id` ???

Comment: You cannot nest aggregation functions (`SUM( . . . GROUP_CONCAT()`)`.  I would suggest that you delete this question and ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: The jargon for your task is *ranking*. It may help you find examples.